# XPath to track if a product is: in stock/its price

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, domxpath, google-sheets-formula

I am a complete beginner who knows a little bit of HTML and Java so my question might sound very dumb.

I'm basically trying to use Google Spreadsheets in order to track the availability of an item/its price [on this website](https://www.artisan-jp.com/fx-hien-eng.html). I'm using the "IMPORTXML" function and have no trouble getting the title of the product or its description. **However I cannot get the price as it needs me to select a size first, which I don't know how to do through the "IMPORTXML" function.**

Right now, this returns "Imported content is empty.":

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.artisan-jp.com/fx-hien-eng.html","//p[@id='price']")
```

Would creating a function through Google Script work? If so, how do I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: When I look at the source code of the web page, I see `<p id="price"></p>`. So I assume the price is loaded dynamically afterwards through Javascript. The price might be hidden here: https://www.artisan-jp.com/get_syouhin.php - but I'm not sure if Google Sheets allows you to do arbitrary HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do fetch any data with `IMPORTXML` since `Javascript` is used to display the price. With `IMPORTFROMWEB` [addon](https://nodatanobusiness.com/importfromweb/), you can activate JS rendering but you'll only get the price of the default product.

[image: IFW]

It's probably better to use `Selenium` + `Python` (or any other language) to achieve your goal. That way you'll be able to click and select a specific product.(size, color, hardness)

If you really want to do this with a Google solution, you'll have to write your own custom function in Google Apps Script (send a `POST` request over a specific url : `https://www.artisan-jp.com/get_syouhin.php`). Something like :

```
function myFunction() {
var formData = {
  'kuni': 'on',
  'sir': '140',
  'size': '1',
  'color': '1',
};

var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'payload' : formData
};

Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.artisan-jp.com/get_syouhin.php', options).getContentText());  
}
```

In the first part (`formData`), your declare the parameters of the POST. These parameters correspond to the properties of the product.

```
Sir :

XSoft = 140
Soft = 141
Mid = 142

Size :

S = 1
M = 2
L = 3
XL = 4

Color :

Red = 1
Black = 5
```

Output :

[image: REQ]

You'll get the reference number, the description of the product and its price.
When the product is not in stock, there's a preceding `NON` in the output.

[image: OOS]

It's up to you now to extract the data of interest from the output and to populate the cells of your workbook.

Assuming your function is named "mouse". Just use `SPLIT` to display the data properly.

```
=SPLIT(mouse();"/")
```

[image: SPLIT]

To extract the price only, you can use `SPLIT` then `QUERY`. `SUBSTITUTE` is used to coerce the result to a number.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(SPLIT(mouse();"/");"select Col4");".";",")*1
```

[image: Price]

Comment: Thank you! As I said I'm a complete beginner trying to learn by setting myself challenges (which appear to be a little too difficult for my current level but it's a lot of fun!). While I understand most of the code, I'm having trouble getting the output. I have tried running the function and just adding "return 1;" at the end and I do get 1 so the spreadsheet recognizes the function. However when I try returning the Logger.log part, it is just blank.

Comment: Update: I just tried "return response.getContentText();" and it worked! How would you extract only part of the data though? It's not essential for my tracker but I'm very curious.